# Scroll end detect to many times in flutter

Tags: flutter, pagination, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

I uses Listview.builder. it detect scroll end to many time that is why API call to many times and add duplicate Data in Listview.

**Code:-**

```
ListView.builder(
    controller: _scrollController
    ..addListener(() async {
  if (_scrollController
      .position.pixels -
      10 ==
      _scrollController.position
          .maxScrollExtent -
          10 &&
      !state.isPaginationLoading) {
    print("Scroll End TEst Screen");
    await ctx
        .read<ProfileCubit>()
        .getProfiles(
        context, true, null);
  }
```

Comment: Don't addListener() like that. In the initState would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont put logic code inside build. In your case `_scrollController` will addListener every times widget build called, cause multiple handle will trigger.

Advice for you is create and put handle logic to a function, put `addListener/removeListener` in `initState/dispose` because they was called only once.

With your problem, you can create a variale to check api was called yet and prevent other call.

```dart
class AppState extends State<App> {
  var scroll = ScrollController();
  var preventCall = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    scroll.addListener(onScroll);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    scroll.removeListener(onScroll);
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future yourFuture() async {}

  void onScroll() {
    var position = scroll.position.pixels;
    if (position >= scroll.position.maxScrollExtent - 10) {
      if (!preventCall) {
        yourFuture().then((_) => preventCall = false);
        preventCall = true;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to check if API call is happening or not and based on it you can you can call the API. You would also need to handle pagination logic if all info is loaded.

Comment: state.ispagination true false according to API call but my scrollcontroller detect 2 time scroll end event at a time. That is my issue

Answer (score -1):

you can always check if you reached at the limit of max Limit of your scroll controller then you can call API

condition is like

```
  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: _controller
                      ..addListener(() async {
                        if (_controller.position.pixels >
                            _controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                          _loadMore();
                        }
                      }),
```

you may be like full example

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Paggination2HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const Paggination2HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Paggination2HomeScreen> createState() => _Paggination2HomeScreenState();
}

class _Paggination2HomeScreenState extends State<Paggination2HomeScreen> {
  final String _baseUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";
  int _page = 1;
  final int _limit = 10;
  bool _hasNextPage = true;
  bool _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
  bool _isLoadMoreRunning = false;
  List _posts = [];

  void _firstLoad() async {
    setState(() {
      _isFirstLoadRunning = true;
    });

    try {
      final res = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("$_baseUrl?_page=$_page&_limit=$_limit"),
      );
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          _posts = jsonDecode(res.body);
        });
        log('receivedData : ${jsonDecode(res.body)}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        log('Something went wrong');
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      _isFirstLoadRunning = false;
    });
  }

  void _loadMore() async {
    if (_hasNextPage == true &&
        _isFirstLoadRunning == false &&
        _isLoadMoreRunning == false) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = true;
      });
      _page++;

      try {
        final res = await http.get(
          Uri.parse('$_baseUrl?_page=$_page&_limit=$_limit'),
        );

        log('url : $_baseUrl?_page=$_page&_limit=$_limit');
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          final List fetchedPost = jsonDecode(res.body);
          if (fetchedPost.isNotEmpty) {
            setState(() {
              _posts.addAll(fetchedPost);
            });
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _hasNextPage = false;
            });
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          log('something went wrong');
        }
      }
      setState(() {
        _isLoadMoreRunning = false;
      });
    }
  }

  // the controller for listyView
  late ScrollController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firstLoad();
    _controller = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.removeListener(_loadMore);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Paggination',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.52),
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        systemOverlayStyle: const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
      body: _isFirstLoadRunning
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25),
              ),
            )
          : Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    controller: _controller
                      ..addListener(() async {
                        if (_controller.position.pixels >
                            _controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
                          _loadMore();
                        }
                      }),
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: _posts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10,
                        vertical: 5,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.065),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                          width: 0.5,
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'ID : ${_posts.elementAt(index)['id']}',
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'AlbumID : ${_posts.elementAt(index)['albumId']}',
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Title : ${_posts.elementAt(index)['title']}',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                child: Image.network(
                                  _posts.elementAt(index)['url'],
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                                child: Image.network(
                                  _posts.elementAt(index)['thumbnailUrl'],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // when the _loadMore running
                if (_isLoadMoreRunning == true)
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20),
                    child: const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                        strokeWidth: 3,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                if (_hasNextPage == false)
                  SafeArea(
                    child: Container(
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                      child: const Text('you get all'),
                    ),
                  )
              ],
            ),
    );
  }
}
```